# Android progressbar not showing up

Tags: progress-bar, android-progressbar

I have a progressbar in android mainactivity.

```
<ProgressBar
 android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
 android:layout_centerInParent="true"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large"
 android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />


public class MainPage extends FragmentActivity
{
     public ProgressBar mProgress; 

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {
           mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
          //setting onbuttonclick call refreshInfo()
     }

     public void refreshInfo()
     {
         GetInfo myTask = new GetInfo(this);
         myTask.execute(excute);
     }
}



public class GetInfo extends AsyncTask class

        @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        activity.mProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

        @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(BusLocations result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        activity.callMainThreadFuctionToDoStuff
        activity.mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
```

Everything works fine except the progressbar never shows up. Just to make sure it's not fast I have added 10 seconds delay in doInBackground.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was ProgressBar location in layout.xml.